# Adding two numbers in the form of a linked list

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm new to JavaScript, I'm trying to solve this problem：

> You are given two non-empty linked lists representing two non-negative
>   integers. The digits are stored in reverse order and each of their
>   nodes contain a single digit. Add the two numbers and return it as a
>   linked list.

This is my solution：

```
addTwoNumbers = (l1, l2) => {
    let carry = 0;
    let p = curr = new ListNode(0);
    while (l1 || l2) {
        sum = 0;
        if (l1 && l2) {
            sum = l1.val + l2.val + carry;
        } else if (l1) {
            sum = l1.val + carry;
        } else if (l2) {
            sum = l2.val + carry;
        }
        carry = sum % 10;
        sum = sum / 10;
        curr.next = new ListNode(sum);
        curr = curr.next;
    }
    return p.next

};
```

The definition of a LL is here,

```
class ListNode{
    constructor(val){
        this.val = val;
        this.next = null;
    }

}
```

This goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: What exactly is `addTwoNumbers` called with? (need a [MCVE])

Comment: Your while loop is testing `while (l1 || l2)` but neither `l1` nor `l2` change in the loop. You probably want to set one of the to their next node in the loop.

Comment: Sample input and expected output is helpful as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code:

```
addTwoNumbers = (l1, l2)=> {
  let carry = 0;
  var curr;
  let p = (curr = new ListNode(0));
  var sum = 0;
  while (l1 || l2) {

    if (l1 && l2) {
      sum = l1.val + l2.val + carry;
      l1=l1.next;
      l2=l2.next;
    } else if (l1) {
      sum = l1.val + carry;
      l1=l1.next;
    } else if (l2) {
      sum = l2.val + carry;
      l2=l2.next;
    }

    carry = Math.floor(sum / 10);
    sum = Math.floor(sum) % 10;
    curr.next = new ListNode(sum);
    curr = curr.next;

  }

  if(carry===1)
    curr.next=new ListNode(carry);
  return p.next;
};
```

Something to note:

1. you have to declare `curr` before using it, also the `sum`.
2. you have to update the `l1`and `l2` reference after each sum.
3. to get the correct `carry` and `sum`, you should notice the difference between `/` and `%`, also that `number` in js is different with other strong type languages such as `java`.
4. after the `while` loop we need an additional logic to deal with the left `carry.`

Answer (score 0):

**This is my version:**

```
const addTwoNumbers = (l1, l2) => {
    let carry = 0;
    let curr = new ListNode(0);
    let p = curr;

    while (l1 || l2) {
        const sum = (l1?.val || 0) + (l2?.val || 0) + carry;
        l1=l1?.next;
        l2=l2?.next;

        carry = sum > 9 ? 1 : 0;
        curr.next = new ListNode(sum % 10);
        curr = curr.next;
    }

    if(!!carry) {
        curr.next = new ListNode(1);
    }
    return p.next;
};
```

This version is the same as the version of [ZhaoGang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2830167/zhaogang), but shorter by using new JavaScript syntaxis - [optional chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

**And another version:**

```
const toArray = (l) => {
    const arr = []
    while(l) {
        arr.push(l.val)
        l = l.next;
    }
    return arr
}

const toList = (arr) => {
    let curr = new ListNode(0);
    let p = curr;
    for(const el of arr) {
        curr.next = new ListNode(el);
        curr = curr.next
    }
    return p.next;
}

const addTwoNumbers = (l1, l2) => {
    const la1 = toArray(l1)
    const la2 = toArray(l2)
    const len1 = la1.length
    const len2 = la2.length
    const lenMax = len1 > len2 ? len1 : len2
    
    let carry = 0;
    const result = []
    for (let i = 0; i < lenMax; i++) {
        const sum = (la1[i] || 0) + (la2[i] || 0) + carry;
        
        carry = sum > 9 ? 1 : 0;
        result.push(sum % 10);
    }
    carry && result.push(1)
    
    return toList(result)   
};
```

1. Transform both lists into arrays
2. Detect the longest array
3. Initialize variables
4. Walk through arrays, calculate `sum` and fill `result` array
5. Transform the `result` array to *Nested List*

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

*why this is not correct?*

```js
var addTwoNumbers = function (l1, l2) {
    
    let num1 = parseInt(reverse(l1).join(''));
    let num2 = parseInt(reverse(l2).join(''));

    const newArr = Array.from(String(num1+num2), Number);

    return reverse(newArr);
};
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33341508)